# MySQL error and possible duplicates running bin/magento setup:upgrade after renaming module

Tags: magento2, module, database, upgrade

I've renamed a custom module from MagicPack_magicheader to MagicPack_Magicheader and trying to now update by running setup:upgrade. I get the following error:

```
  [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]                                                                                                                                                                      
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'MagicPack_Magicheader' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `setup_module` (`module`, `schema_version`) VALUES (?, ?)  



  [PDOException]                                                                                                   
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'MagicPack_Magicheader' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

On the site itself, it tells me to run upgrade, but I've noticed two entries:

```
The following modules are outdated:
MagicPack_Magicheader schema: current version - none, required version - 0.2.0
MagicPack_Magicheader data: current version - none, required version - 0.2.0
```

This seems to match the issue with duplicate entries. Can anyone let me know why there are duplicate entries, one for schema and one for data? The module.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MagicPack_Magicheader" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove the generated tables by that extension.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is easy to fix, follow the instructions.

1. Find **setup_module** table name in the database.
2. Then, find the row which contains the name of your module in **setup_module** table (In your case, module_name is **MagicPack_Magicheader**) and delete this row (when you run setup:upgrade it will be automatically re-generate)

   ```
   DELETE FROM setup_module where module = 'Module_Name'
   ```
3. Then, run the command **bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**Reason:** Your old module information already exists, so whenever you run setup upgrade, it is throwing **Duplicate entry** error. After removing old module information its successfully get upgrade.

have good luck.

Comment: welcome @MichaelWatson

Comment: This is incomplete - what do you do when you find 'setup_module'?

Comment: I don't even have setup_module table in Magento DB. My store is running Magento 2.4.2. Would the table have changed in this version?